# Как программно скопировать файлы из internal storage на внешную Usb Mass storage device

Tags: android, usb

Как программно скопировать файлы из internal storage на внешную Usb Mass Storage Device подсоединенную по OTG. Понятно, как через UsbManager получить устройство и определить что это Mass Storage Device, но как потом достучаться к его файловой системе не понятно. Читал, что это возможно с помощью Storage Access Framework, но подобных примеров не обнаружил.

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075352/get-access-to-usb-mass-storage-device-in-android)

Comment: @TimurVI, спасибо,видел это решение  - не нравится, что там путь к usb захардкоден, а у меня каждый раз будет новая флешка.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала получаем список корневых папок:

```
File roots[]=File.listRoots();
```

Далее в цикле проверяем корень физически отсоединяемый или нет:

```
Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(File );
```

Если он отсоединяемый это флешка.

Comment: Ок, а смогу ли я потом писать и читать с этой флешки или прав у меня не будет?

Comment: Это другой вопрос. Зависит от версии Android'а и вида устройства... Оформляйте новый вопрос или поищите здесь, многократно освещалась тема

Comment: Да нет, я как раз так и спросил, как скопировать программно на флешку. Я проверил на работе ваше решение - оно не дало мне пути к юсб накопителяем, плюс как я прочел на андроид доках - ваш вариант вернул бы истину и sd картой, что для меня ошибочно.

Comment: Да вас не поймешь спрашиваете как программно скопировать, а в комментах пишете как найти юсб флешку - можно как то быть более организованным что ли?

Comment: во-первых я НЕ писал как найти USB флешку, если вы читали чей-то другой вопрос о поиске USB устройств и параллельно пытались ответить на мой, так кому из нас, необходимо быть более организованным? Вы сходу дали мне ответ на вопрос как найти путь к флешке( причем не правильный ответ), а теперь еще и обижаетесь, наверное, на то, что я сказал, что ответ ошибочен и отмечать как правильный  я его не буду. Внимательнее надо быть.

Comment: С точки зрения API прогера SD карта или usb флешка одно и то же, ну если только не лезть в низкоуровневые дебри - это во первых, а во вторых, я никогда ни на кого не обижаюсь, просто делаю выводы о личности ТС и иду дальше - так что идите с миром :)